# Unity 5 C# GUI - Progress Bar not starting at 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason my progress bar is going backwards instead of forwards, it doesn't seem to be starting at 0. It starts at 1 and counts down to 0. How can I make this code start at 0 and count up so the progress bar goes forward instead of backwards?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Distance : MonoBehaviour {

private float finalGoal_dist = 0.0f;
public Transform Player;
public Transform finalGoal;


public Vector2 pos = new Vector2(20, 40);
public Vector2 size = new Vector2(120, 20);
public Texture2D emptyTex;
public Texture2D fullTex;


float t = 0;
float initialDistance;




void Start(){
    initialDistance = Vector2.Distance(Player.position, finalGoal.position);
    // print("Distance to Goal:" + initialDistance);
}


void OnGUI(){
            t = finalGoal_dist / initialDistance;
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x, size.y), emptyTex);
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x*t, size.y), fullTex);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    finalGoal_dist = Vector2.Distance(Player.position, finalGoal.position);
    //print("Distance to Goal:" + finalGoal_dist);
    print(t);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand it's working properlly but starting at 0. You need to use size.x*(1-t), so it takes the full width minus the % that has been udpated.

Try this:

> ```
> GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x, size.y), emptyTex);
> GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x*(1-t), size.y), fullTex);
> ```